# Não estou entendendo a sintaxe dessa linha de código de uma função:

Tags: react, typescript, return

```
  const handleRemoveFromCart = (id: number) => {
    setCartItems(prev =>
      prev.reduce((ack, item) => {
        if (item.id === id) {
          if (item.amount === 1) return ack;
          return [...ack, { ...item, amount: item.amount - 1 }];
        } else {
          return [...ack, item];
        }
      }, [] as CartItemType[])
    );
  };
```

Essa função consiste em remover uma unidade de um item no carrinho de compras assim que o botão for clicado e retornar o resultado. Mas eu não entendi a forma que essa linha de código está escrita.

A minha duvida é essa, porque ele está retornando o spread de ack(acumulador) e logo depois o spread de item e o amount: item.amount - 1 entre chaves ?

Eu queria entender o funcionamento da sintaxe dessa linha de código que consiste em remover uma unidade do item no carrinho de compras.

```
return [...ack, {...item, amount: item.amount - 1}];
```

Answer (score -2):

De forma resumida, o item.amount - 1, ele está exatamente reduzindo um da quantidade total do item . o spread do ...item , ele retorna o item após sofrer a alteração, agora o spread no acumulator nao consegui entender muito bem também.